# NullPointer when implementing custom listview with image and text usingn baseadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

so I have been following a tutorial [here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/) with a couple things added. When I try running the app I get a nullpointer error saying that

```
rowItems.add(item);
```

which I am going to assume means item is null but I set item earlier like so

```
item = new RowItem(id,image,name,distance,date,time,dist_display,timeAway);
```

Now none of those should be null(the items going into RowItem).

I'm not sure where to start for figuring this out so any help would be greatly appreciated! If I need to add more code to show more of what is going on just let me know.

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

EDIT:

```
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261): Process: com.skateconnect, PID: 26261
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261):    at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity$LoadAllSpots.doInBackground(AllSpotsActivity.java:513)
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261):    at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity$LoadAllSpots.doInBackground(AllSpotsActivity.java:1)
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-13 13:30:29.406: E/AndroidRuntime(26261):    ... 3 more
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42151fb0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity$LoadAllSpots.onPreExecute(AllSpotsActivity.java:376)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at com.skateconnect.AllSpotsActivity$3.onClick(AllSpotsActivity.java:257)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18498)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-13 13:30:29.936: E/WindowManager(26261):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 513 is rowItems.add(item);

EDIT2:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        int n=0;
        search_trig=0;
        String type=null;
        String date=null;
        String time=null;
        int image;
        RowItem item=null;

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Spots: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products

                if(add.equals("Event")){
                    spots = json.getJSONArray("events");
                }else{
                    spots = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SPOTS);
                }


                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < spots.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = spots.getJSONObject(i);
                    search_trig=0;

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String strlong = c.getString(TAG_LONG);
                    double elong = Double.parseDouble(strlong);
                    String strlat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                    double elat = Double.parseDouble(strlat);
                    double dist = getDistance(slat, slong, elat, elong);
                    String distance = String.format("%.1f", dist);
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String pave = c.getString(TAG_PAVEMENT);
                    String traffic = c.getString(TAG_TRAFFIC);
                    String enviro = c.getString(TAG_ENVIRONMENT);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String image_B64 = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_B64);
                    String dist_display = distance+ " Mi";
                    String timeAway=".";
                    type=".";
                    date=".";
                    time=".";
                    //EVENT STUFF
                    if(add.equals("Event")){
                        //need to add other stuff too
                        type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                        date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                        time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);
                        timeAway = String.valueOf(getTimeAWAY(date));
                    }
                    image = getDispImage(type,enviro);
                    if(search_bp==1){
                        //checks distance
                        if(str_dist.equals("Any")==false){
                        if((dist>Double.parseDouble(str_dist))){
                            search_trig=1;
                        }
                        }

                        if(str_pavement.equals("Any")==false){
                        if((str_pavement.equals(pave)==false)){
                            search_trig=1;
                        }
                        }

                        if(str_traffic.equals("Any")==false){
                        if((str_traffic.equals(traffic)==false)){
                            search_trig=1;
                        }
                        }

                        if(str_enviro.equals("Any")==false){
                        if((str_enviro.equals(enviro)==false)){
                            search_trig=1;
                        }
                        }

                        //EVENT STUFF
                        if(add.equals("Event")){

                            if(str_type.equals("Any")==false){
                                if((str_type.equals(type)==false)){
                                    search_trig=1;
                                }
                                }

                        }
                        item = new RowItem(id,image,name,distance,date,time,dist_display,timeAway);
                        shr_spots.put(id, new SHARE(id, name,strlong,strlat,pave,traffic,enviro,image_B64,date,time,type)); 


                        if(search_trig == 0){
                            //spotsList.add(map); 
                            rowItems.add(item);
                            n=1;
                        }
                    }else{
                        //spotsList.add(map);
                         rowItems.add(item);

                        n=1;
                    }
                }
                if(n==0){
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No "+add+" found with those specifications.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                           }
                        });
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewSpotActivity.class);
                finish();
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

513 is the second

```
rowItems.add(item);
```

Just because of which button I pressed, if I had pressed the other then it would have been the first giving the error.

Comment: Please post your stacktrace.

Comment: If that line is where you get the exception then it's due to `rowItems` being `null` not `item`. But yes, logcat please.

Comment: did you initialize `rowItems` before adding?

Comment: please post `AllSpotsActivity$LoadAllSpots.doInBackground` and show `AllSpotsActivity.java:513`

Comment: updated with logcat rowitems is just set as: List<RowItem> rowItems;, items is initialized as null though at the beginning as: RowItem item=null;

Comment: i don't see anywhere that you initialize `rowItems`, did you initialize that?

Comment: It is intialized in: public class AllSpotsActivity extends ListActivity {
...
 List<RowItem> rowItems;...}

Comment: and did you call `rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();` ?

Comment: no I did not :( thank you!